# Problema para pegar valores do Input do tipo Hidden em PHP

Tags: php

Primeiro, eu fiz dois formulários com um input do tipo hidden cada:

```
<form action="painel.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" value="aluno" name = "auth">
    <input type="submit" value="Aluno">
</form>
<br>
<form action="painel.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" value="adm" name = "auth">
    <input type="submit" value="Adm">
</form>
```

Depois, Eu tentei pegar o valor de um input hidden no início da página "painel.php":

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $auth = $_POST['auth'];
?>
```

Mas, aparece este problema:

Warning: Undefined array key "auth" in C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\trabalho\painel.php on line 3

O que eu faço?

Comment: Se tirar o `hidden`, ele envia certo?

Comment: A própria mensagem de erro está te dizendo o que fazer. Dá um echo '<pre>'; 
 print_r($_POST); ou  um var_dump($_POST); em painel.php e veja o que você está submetendo  no formulário.

Comment: ThRnk, eu não sei como fazer sem o Hidden, pois eu preciso dessa informação para verificar as informações do login no banco de dados, se for aluno ele verifica na tabela do aluno e se for adm ele verifica na tabela do adm.

Comment: Marcos Xavier, eu dei um echo e um print_r mas deu o mesmo problema.

Comment: E se você deixar junto o igual (=)? Que está assim `name = "auth"` para assim `name="auth"?`

Comment: Adventistaam, deu certo kkkkk

Não sei nem como

Comment: Obrigado a todos que tentaram me ajudar, tenham um bom dia.

Comment: Isso não interfere em nada no php, creio que seja alguma outra alteração que tenha feito no seu código. Faça o teste como estava anteriormente e posta aqui. Estou usando o php 7.3

Comment: @ThauanFernandesAraújo Que bom que deu certo

Comment: Uso o php 8.0.2, eu coloquei do jeito que estava antes e deu certo.

Não sei o que era

Comment: Cuidado com caches rsrs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thauan,

`$_POST['auth']` só passa a existir depois que você clicar pela primeira vez em um dos dois botões (envia o formulário). Na primeira vez que abrir a página ele não existe e dá o alerta.

Se você enviou o formulário uma vez e ficou apertando F5 para verificar as alterações no PHP, o navegador reenvia os dados do formulário e parece que resolveu.

Para evitar o alerta verifique se o parâmetro foi passado. Altere sua linha `$auth = $_POST['auth']` para:

- `$auth = (isset($_POST['auth']) ? $_POST['auth'] : "nenhum");`
- ou: `$auth = $_POST['auth'] ?? "nenhum";`

Observação importante:

Se você está utilizando `input hidden` para definir a atribuição, você colocou toda a segurança na mão do usuário. Faça a verificação no lado do PHP com o próprio banco de dados informando o papel do usuário.